# Officedown: rpptx no carga el template de power point

Tags: r, r-markdown

Quiero usar un template institucional para crear una presentación. Cuando uso rmarkdown, el template carga correctamente:

```
---
title: "rmarkdown prueba"
author: "author"
date: "dd/mm/aaaa"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: Template.pptx
    ---


## slide

prueba
```

Sin embargo, officedown no detecta el template:

```
---
title: "Officedown prueba"
output: 
  officedown::rpptx_document:
  reference_doc: Template.pptx
---


## slide

prueba
```

Esta es la salida de la consola con officedown:

```
  |......................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


"C:/.../RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testing_officedown.knit.md --to pptx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output testing_officedown.pptx --reference-doc "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqOCOzt\file17e03f756d38.pptx" 


processing file: testing_officedown.Rmd
output file: testing_officedown.knit.md


Output created: testing_officedown.pptx
```

Vale aclarar que officedown genera el ppt, pero usando el template default, no el que indico. En la consola no muestra ningún warning, error o aclaración que me de una pista del problema. Busqué en github https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues y no encontré nada útil al respecto.

Gracias de antemano